# How can you delete all log files from an Azure WebApp using powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure, kudu

As part of our CI process, I'd like to clear out all of the log files on our App Service before deploying new code to it.  I believe the best way to do this is with a KUDU API call using a PowerShell script.  I believe that I need to pass it a command.  So this is what I've come up with so far based on some other similar questions asked.  However, when I run this, I get a "Error 403 - This web app is stopped." response back.  So I'm doing something wrong.

The important part is the "$kudoApiCommand".

```
param(
    [string]$resourceGroupName,
    [string]$webAppName,
    [string]$slotName=""
)
function Get-AzureRmWebAppPublishingCredentials($resourceGroupName, $webAppName, $slotName = $null){
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($slotName)){
        $resourceType = "Microsoft.Web/sites/config"
        $resourceName = "$webAppName/publishingcredentials"
    }
    else{
        $resourceType = "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/config"
        $resourceName = "$webAppName/$slotName/publishingcredentials"
    }
    $publishingCredentials = Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName 
    $resourceGroupName -ResourceType $resourceType -ResourceName 
    $resourceName -Action list -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
    Write-Host $publishingCredentials   
    return $publishingCredentials
}

function Get-KuduApiAuthorisationHeaderValue($resourceGroupName,$webAppName, $slotName = $null){
    $publishingCredentials = Get-AzureRmWebAppPublishingCredentials $resourceGroupName $webAppName $slotName
    Write-Host $publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingUserName
    Write-Host $publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingPassword
    return ("Basic {0}" -f [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingUserName, $publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingPassword))))
}

function Delete-WebAppLogFiles($resourceGroupName, $webAppName, $slotName = ""){

    $kuduApiAuthorisationToken = Get-KuduApiAuthorisationHeaderValue 
    $resourceGroupName $webAppName $slotName
    if ($slotName -eq ""){
        $kuduApiUrl = "https://$webAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/command"
    }
    else{
        $kuduApiUrl = "https://$webAppName`-$slotName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/command"
    }

    $kudoApiCommand = @{
        command='del * /S /Q'
        dir='d:\\home\\LogFiles'
    }

    Write-Output $kuduApiUrl
    Write-Output $kuduApiAuthorisationToken
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $kuduApiUrl `
                    -Headers @{"Authorization"=$kuduApiAuthorisationToken;"If-Match"="*"} `
                    -Method POST
                    -Body $kudoApiCommand
}

Delete-WebAppLogFiles $resourceGroupName $webAppName $slotName
```

Answer (score 2):

Got it. This is what worked for me:

```
param(
    [string]$resourceGroupName,
    [string]$webAppName,
    [string]$slotName=""
)
function Get-AzureRmWebAppPublishingCredentials($resourceGroupName, $webAppName, $slotName = $null){
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($slotName)){
        $resourceType = "Microsoft.Web/sites/config"
        $resourceName = "$webAppName/publishingcredentials"
    }
    else{
        $resourceType = "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/config"
        $resourceName = "$webAppName/$slotName/publishingcredentials"
    }
    $publishingCredentials = Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceType $resourceType -ResourceName $resourceName -Action list -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
    Write-Host $publishingCredentials   
    return $publishingCredentials
}
function Get-KuduApiAuthorizationHeaderValue($resourceGroupName, $webAppName, $slotName = $null){
    $publishingCredentials = Get-AzureRmWebAppPublishingCredentials $resourceGroupName $webAppName $slotName
    Write-Host $publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingUserName
    Write-Host $publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingPassword
    return ("Basic {0}" -f [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingUserName, $publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingPassword))))
}
function Delete-WebAppLogFiles($resourceGroupName, $webAppName, $slotName = ""){

    $apiAuthorizationToken = Get-KuduApiAuthorizationHeaderValue $resourceGroupName $webAppName $slotName
    if ($slotName -eq ""){
        $apiUrl = "https://$webAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/command"
    }
    else{
        $apiUrl = "https://$webAppName`-$slotName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/command"
    }

    $apiCommand = @{
        #command='del *.* /S /Q /F'
        command = 'powershell.exe -command "Remove-Item -path d:\\home\\LogFiles\\* -recurse"'
        dir='d:\\home\\LogFiles'
    }

    Write-Output $apiUrl
    Write-Output $apiAuthorizationToken
    Write-Output $apiCommand
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{"Authorization"=$apiAuthorizationToken;"If-Match"="*"} -Method POST -ContentType "application/json" -Body (ConvertTo-Json $apiCommand)

}

Delete-WebAppLogFiles $resourceGroupName $webAppName $slotName
```