# Best practices for azure webapp loging and automate log clearing policy (in the case log size is increasing )

Tags: azure, logging, azure-web-app-service

1. I'm setting up Azure WebApp logging. My concern is that error logs are stored in webapp server level, the size increasing day by day from Elmah. Is there a best approach to maintaining the logs, both storing and automating archiving or deleting?
2. My web development is based on angular. Any suggestion for aggregating logs, like what kind of logs would be generated?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by default, logs are not automatically deleted (with the exception of Application Logging (Filesystem)). To automatically delete logs, set the Retention Period (Days) field. You could automate the deletion by leveraging KUDU Virtual File System (VFS) Rest API. For a sample script, checkout this discussion thread for a similar approach: 
[How can you delete all log files from an Azure WebApp using powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48584849/how-can-you-delete-all-log-files-from-an-azure-webapp-using-powershell)

Just to highlight, these are the logging that you could capture on WebApps:

•   Detailed Error Logging

•   Failed Request Tracing

•   Web Server Logging

•   Application logging - you can turn on the file system option temporarily for debugging purposes. This option turns off automatically in 12 hours. You can also turn on the blob storage option to select a blob container to write logs to.

For log directory information kindly refer to this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs

Comment: Thanks for sharing your insights, present working on it on powershell script as you shared.